# dot pronoun fails on some systems but not others

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two systems.

The following code passes on `System A` but not on `System B`.

```
responses <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,2,3,4),b = c(0,1,2,3,4))
section_vars <- c("a","b")

mutate_each(responses, funs(mean),one_of(section_vars)) %>%
    mutate(col1 =
             rowSums(
               select(.,one_of(section_vars)),
               na.rm = TRUE
             ) %>% as.integer()
    ) %>% .$col1
```

It fails with the error:

```
Error "." not found
```

System A (Working):

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dataBroker_1.141.0.0 dplyr_0.5.0          tidyr_0.5.1         
[4] data.table_1.9.6     RMySQL_0.10.9        DBI_0.4-1           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5       codetools_0.2-14  withr_1.0.2       digest_0.6.9     
 [5] psych_1.6.6       foreach_1.4.3     assertthat_0.1    plyr_1.8.4       
 [9] chron_2.3-47      R6_2.1.2          magrittr_1.5      lazyeval_0.2.0   
[13] doParallel_1.0.10 devtools_1.12.0   iterators_1.0.8   tools_3.2.3      
[17] parallel_3.2.3    yaml_2.1.13       mnormt_1.5-4      memoise_1.0.0    
[21] tibble_1.0
```

System B (Error):

```
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dataBroker_1.141.0.2 dplyr_0.5.0          tidyr_0.5.1          data.table_1.9.6     RMySQL_0.9-3         DBI_0.3.1           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.4      codetools_0.2-14 psych_1.4.8.11   foreach_1.4.2    assertthat_0.1   plyr_1.8.1       chron_2.3-47     R6_2.1.2         magrittr_1.0.1   lazyeval_0.1.10  doParallel_1.0.8
[12] iterators_1.0.7  tools_3.2.5      yaml_2.1.13      parallel_3.2.5
```

Comment: Maybe update `magrittr` on B? You're running version 1.5 on A and 1.0.1 on B, and it is the package that defines `%>% ` and the corresponding `.`.

Comment: @gregor Thanks! I will try this.

Comment: I thought `%>%` and `.` were both contained in `dplyr`?

Comment: They are defined in `magrittr`. `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and several other packages import them. See the "reverse depends" and "reverse imports" list [on the magrittr CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/index.html).

Comment: Or, more directly, line 536 [of dplyr's NAMESPACE file](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/NAMESPACE).

Comment: Unfortunately the `magrittr` NEWS file doesn't have much historical information so it's difficult to know what changes have been made since version 1.0.1. If this does fix the problem it might be worth filing an issue with `dplyr` to add a minimum version requirement to its import of `magrittr`.

Comment: @Gregor can you post your comment as an answer. You correctly identified the problem. I was at my wits end there! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%>%` operator comes from the `magrittr` package, so make sure your `magrittr` version is up-to-date.